# Count all records in a table

Tags: symfony-1.4

I need to count all records in a single table, so ..In my action

```
public function executeTesting(sfWebrequest $r) 
{
$this->applicants = Doctrine_core::getTable('Applicants')->count();
$this->setLayout(false);
}
```

and I can display the records in a template
testingSucess.php

```
 <?php echo $applicants ?>//returns number of records example 890
```

But I want it to display in another templates.Let say I want to 'embed' to another template(failureSuccess.php).Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consider using an AJAX call, and making a little change at your code you can avoid the template.
So let's change your action to this:

```
class miscActions extends sfActions
{
  public function executeTotal(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $total = Doctrine::getTable('Utenti')->findAll()->count();

    return $this->renderText(json_encode(array('total' => $total)));
  }
}
```

And now you can retrieve that value in a template with, for example, jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo url_for("misc/total") ?>',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
      console.log("Total: " + data.total);

      // And if you want to update a div content
      $("#responsecontainer").html(data.total);
    }
  });

</script>
```

Comment: can you show complete code example?I  have little understanding in json and jQuery.My module is 'misc' and action is 'total'.I tried url: '<?php echo url_for('misc/total')?>, type: "json", success: function(data){
        // inside data.total you have your value                   
            $("#responsecontainer").data(total); 
      } and in my templates <div id ="responsecontaner"><div>

Comment: @ilSalvo you're so nice.Keep it up

Answer (score 0):

Got it..Just remove the action and create a helper instead,so in my lib/helper/TotalHelper.php

```
<?php

 function getTotal() {
$applicants = Doctrine_core::getTable('Applicants')->count();

    return $applicants;
}
```

and in template (failureSuccess.php)

```
<?php use_helper('Total') ?>
<?php echo getTotal() ?>
```

So convenient..

Comment: The helper functions are not meant to make any queries to DB. If you need a part in different templates you should either include it in all of your actions or create a component which will make the query to the DB and display it properly.